# Espresso Framework - consistent cross-controller rendering?

Tags: ruby

I have a basic CMS and i'm hugely using cross-controller rendering within it.

```
class Index < E
  map '/'

  # some actions

  def ad
    @steroids = render_p('anabolic-steroids/ads/left-banner')
    # some logic
  end
end
```

`Steroids` class:

```
class Steroids < E
  map 'anabolic-steroids'

  # actions
end
```

View folder:

```
view/
  |
  - anabolic-steroids/
      |
      - ads/
          |
          - left-banner.erb
  # other templates
```

Everything works well, but now customer wants `anabolic-steroids` URL 
to be renamed into `steroids`

To make this work i remapped `Steroids` class:

```
map :steroids
```

and renamed `view/anabolic-steroids/` folder to `view/steroids/`.

And `Steroids` controller works well with new URL.

But now all other controllers that were rendering steroids ad are broken :(

And i have to find all places where it is used and rename

```
render_p('anabolic-steroids/ads/left-banner')
```

to

```
render_p('steroids/ads/left-banner')
```

Odd!

I have also other lot of places where i'm using cross-controller rendering like this.

Any way to avoid useless refactoring
when such innocent renaming requests comes from customers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite long description for a slightly trivial issue :) (joking, sorry, good question though)

The solution is simple, really simple - **never use strings where you can use something else...**

Seems you missed this on documentation - **"To render a template of inner controller, pass controller as first argument and the template as second."**

See [official docs here](http://e.github.com/ViewAPI.html#rendering-templates)

So to survive any renaming issues use cross-controller rendering like this:

```
render_p(Steroids, 'ads/left-banner')
```

Now you should not worry about "innocent renaming requests" :)